# qgis 2.8.1 date filter gives incorrect selection results

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, date

I am running QGIS 2.8.1 on ubuntu 14.04 x64. I applied a date filter to a shapefile using the layer Properties_General "Query Builder" button. So the query was

```
 "LOCATION START DATE" >= '01/01/2014'
```

The selection does filter out a bunch of objects, however in the selection results I am still seeing objects with dates before 2014. I am not sure why that is.

I even tried to use a function like:

```
 todate("LOCATION START DATE") >= '01/01/2014'
```

but that gave me an error.

Is there something I am missing to get a working date filter?